# Retrieve both eth* and "long" names (manufacturer) for every network interface?

Tags: shell-script, network-interface

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Following the examples on https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-network-cards-command/, I can use

```
# lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
```

to get manufacturer names of devices:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761e Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
```

Then, I can use:

```
# ifconfig -a
```

or

```
# ip link show
```

... to show something like:

```
1: lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::baac:6fff:fe65:31e5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But is there a command, that will allow me to list both "short" device names `eth0` and "long" ones (that is, Manufacturer, model) for all network interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Found this as I was writing the question:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network | grep 'logical\|description\|product\|vendor\|\*-'
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       logical name: enp1s0
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       logical name: wlp2s0
```

Seems to work fine, but would love to hear if there is another way to achieve this.

Comment: What would you want to do differently? If `lshw` gives the information you want, then why not use it? Or would you just want the information presented in some other way?

Comment: thanks @ilkkachu - mostly would like to know if there is any other application that can extract both pieces of information (as I'm kind of surprised that, say, `ifconfig` has no option to print manufacturer etc); otherwise I'm happy with `lshw` output